# Is this description of alternatives in regexes wrong?

Tags: python, regex, peg

The wikipedia article on [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) states:

> The fundamental difference between
>   context-free grammars and parsing
>   expression grammars is that the PEG's
>   choice operator is ordered. If the
>   first alternative succeeds, the second
>   alternative is ignored. Thus ordered
>   choice is not commutative, unlike
>   unordered choice as in context-free
>   grammars and regular expressions.

But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787670/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-advice-that-the-substrings-in-regex-should-be-order/) has discovered that if the alternatives are substrings of each other; then regexes do not behave according to `unordered choice`. The wiki is correct for most part but does not take care of this edge condition. Am I correct in my assessment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"regex" != "regular expression". The latter are pure and simple and of interest only to theoretical computer scientists and symbolic mathematicians.

"ordered choice" is an implementation option of regex processors.

You say "if the alternatives are substrings of each other; then regexes do not behave according to unordered choice".

A much more correct statement would be "Some regex processors use ordered choice for ALL alternations. This becomes noticeable when an alternative is a prefix of another."

Comment: What you call "regex" is often referred to as regular expressions, and I argue that it's also correct (for example the [JavaDoc of the Java class `Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) claims that it is "A compiled representation of a regular expression."). It is true, however that there are two related but separate things at work: pure mathematical regular expression and "real-world" computing regular expressions. They are based on the same theories, but are **not** equivalent.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware that they were different. I am working off python's doc which has a "regular expression HOWTO".

Comment: When "regular expressions" are mentioned in the same breath as "context-free grammars" and "parsing expression grammars", what is meant are the pure and simple regular expressions.